# Jsp use if else with jstl

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

How can I translate this Java code as Jstl tags?Thanks

```
String var;
if(condition 1 == true)
   var="Hello1";
else
   var="Hello2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<c:choose>` with `<c:when>` and <`c:otherwise`>

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{condition1}">
        <c:set var="var" value="Hello1"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="var" value="Hello2"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

[Some docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

Comment: Is "myvar" visible outside the <c:choose> tag?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it is. Because you set it in both `when` and `otherwise` branches. If you only used `when`, then it could happen it isn't set if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: if i put myvar into c:out , is this code right? `<c:out value="${myvar}"/>`

Comment: And if i put only ${myvar} without <c:out tag are they the same thing?

Comment: @Alex Yes, `<c:out>` just offers some more options (see [docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm)). You can use `${myvar}` like any other variable on the page.

Comment: But if i put myvar into a <c:out> i don't see its contents?Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65824/discussion-between-predrag-maric-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
<% 
pageContext.setAttribute("condtion", condtion);
%>
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${condition == true }">
       <c:set var="var" value="Hello1" />
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="var" value="Hello2" />
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```